# Is there a way to specifically style all the table cells on the left, or a specific column?

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-selectors

I'm working on a HTML table, and I'm looking for a way to stylize all the cells on the left quickly. Should I just use a class for each of the appropriate `<td>` tags, or is there a CSS selector that looks for the ones on the left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this using the `first-child` selector.

```
table td:first-child {
    color:blue; 
}
```

Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/9p518dp7/